# Adding a Panel to MFC application (Visual Studio C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am really sorry if this is a dumb question - I am new in Visual Studio and can't find an answer to this. Probably because it should be really obvious, but just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, creating a dialog-based MFC application. I would like to draw on a panel, but when I try to add a panel to my dialog - there just is no panel! What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MFC has no concept of panels. The only suggestions I can offer are either to write a custom control or look for a third party MFC controls library which offers what you need.

If you're just trying to separate content, perhaps a group box with no title would do?

Comment: Thank you. Had no idea. Since some MFC concepts do seem a bit outdated, I am probably going to just use .NET (Windows Forms) instead.

Comment: If you want the panel to draw on, just draw directly on the window, @neuro.